# lldb frame variable command no return when debugging apps in iPhone

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, reverse, lldb

when i enter the frame variable of lldb command ,there is no output in the terminal  ,i can not see the variables of current frame,what the problem ,tell me why.

[there is no output  in the  terminal  when  i  enter  "frame variable" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0mVh.png)

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Usually more details would help

With that said, in your case the issue is pretty obviously that you're stopped in mach_msg_trap

You are highly unlikely to have debug information for the kernel - and since you don't, LLDB doesn't know which variables exist in that function, so it doesn't show any

Comment: Process 49612 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xc1cc, 0x0000000100426af0 JuMei`___lldb_unnamed_function24595$$JuMei, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100426af0 JuMei`___lldb_unnamed_function24595$$JuMei
JuMei`___lldb_unnamed_function24595$$JuMei:
-> 0x100426af0:  stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!
   0x100426af4:  stp    fp, lr, [sp, #16]
   0x100426af8:  add    fp, sp, 16
   0x100426afc:  sub    sp, sp, #16
(lldb) frame info
frame #0: 0x0000000100426af0 JuMei`___lldb_unnamed_function24595$$JuMei
(lldb) frame variable
(lldb) thread backtrace

Comment: I'm sorry ,the problem is that the command of  "frame variable " return nothing.It did not stop in mach_msg_trap.It stop at a breakpoint.

Comment: I agree with @zhmeifu I see the same /Users/dyl/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-06-05 at 7.09.06 PM.png

Comment: Same for me ---> (lldb) frame info
frame #0: 0x0000000194012ea4 UIKit`-[UIViewController viewDidAppear:] ---> but no info for frame variable